# can't add image to HTML

Tags: html

i am struggling to add any images whatsoever to html, for them to show when i open in browser

i have tried different images, using them in the correct directories, relative and absolute url

i really do not know why im getting nothing to show...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<title> how to</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <img src="‪https://static1.squarespace.com/static/503264b0e4b0dbdecd41e3f6/t/590a05131e5b6ce08768b593/1493828890055/polaroid2.png"/>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

even the image address copied won't show

any ideas???

Comment: Have you looked at your developer's error console? There should be one in any browser if you go to developer tools (F12). There should be an error log section to help you out.

Comment: this is the message i get on developer       
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Answer (score 4):

As shown in the figure below, there is a special character in your url, causing the browser to treat it as a file on your server instead of on squarespace. Remove that, and your image should be displayed as normal.

[image: Your code]

Comment: how would i remove it? i can't see that character anywhere

Comment: Delete all text from src to https, which should include that invisible character. Then retype it manually @TheoWright

Comment: @TheoWright the character is unicode 8234,  which is a unicode control char, enforcing the text following it to be left-to-right embedding. You probably copied it from where you copied that code. As it is invisible by default, you have to use an advanced editor like vim to see it. But by removing a section of code including that character in any editors, you can remove that character without seeing it.

Answer (score -2):

```
<body>
  <div>
    <img src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/503264b0e4b0dbdecd41e3f6/t/590a05131e5b6ce08768b593/1493828890055/polaroid2.png"/>
  </div>
</body>
```

This seems to work, deleted first double quotes and then added it back
Or delete the first quotes and then the first h to be sure, then retype

Comment: okay great, thanks...

can somebody explain how i would find the extra character that i needed to delete, how was it found in the above comment?

Comment: I just did - I just removed the first double quotes and then typed it back